# Getting error while connecting to Postgres from NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
error: syntax error at or near ","
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (E:\nodejs workspace\node_project2\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (E:\nodejs workspace\node_project2\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (E:\nodejs workspace\node_project2\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs workspace\node_project2\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  length: 90,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '95',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1149',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the SQL statement you are running.

Comment: pool.query(
            'INSERT INTO registration(id, firstname, lastname, gender, email, password, "number") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',

Comment: Well yes, `?` is a syntax error. Postgres uses `$1`, `$2` etc for [parameterised queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).